# Getting Spreadsheet from Row in Open Xml

Tags: c#, openxml

I am working on a Openxml Excel Processing project. In a certain class I have the Row object.
Can I get the current Spreadsheet of this Row object using only Row object?

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft openxml SDK?

Comment: **yes...** I am using **Microsoft Open XML SDK 2.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Parent` property of your `Row` instance to
navigate to the `Worksheet` the row belongs to.

The following [MSDN article on the Row class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.row.aspx) clearly says that the only parent element
of a `Row` instance is the `SheetData` object the row belongs to.
The only possible Parent object of the `SheetData` object is the
`Worksheet` instance (please see the following [MSDN article on the SheetData class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetdata.aspx) for more information).

Example:

The following example shows how to navigate to the `Worksheet`
a given `Row` instance belongs to. For convenience I've created
a extension method:

```
public static class RowExtensionMethods
{
  public static Worksheet GetWorksheet(this Row r)
  {
    if (r.Parent == null)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Row does not belong to sheetdata.");
    }

    if (r.Parent.Parent == null)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Row does not belong to worksheet.");
    }

    return (Worksheet)r.Parent.Parent;
  }
}


// Then in your method use the extension method like so
public void YourMethod(Row r)
{
  Worksheet w = r.GetWorksheet();

  // Do something with the worksheet...
}
```